Mysql database insertion delay through python
currently i am working on the python project that connects to mysql database using pymysql library of python. i have to insert around 5000 rows using stored procedure present in database.but for a single row insertion it is taking 1-2 seconds(via python code).below is this function(you can assume that connection has succesfully made)
    def execute_write_stored_procedure(self, procedure_name, args=None):
        try:

            with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.callproc(procedure_name, args)

            self.connection.commit()  
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            #raising error in case of any error
            raise Exception(f"Errorn in execute_write_stored_procedure function : {e}") from e 

for loop for row insertion :
for row in rows:
   execute_write_stored_procedure('procedure_name',row)

i have checked the database and each and every row has a successfull insertion,but is taking too long .i don't know how to solve this, because this is bare minimum code you can have.note that this is single row insertion alogrithm, stored procedure is not designed for bulk insert, although i have tried all the possible libraries like pymysql,cymysql,mysqldb i have tried multithreading, pooling, pymysql.executemany but none of them worked.any help would be appricieted!!

Do you have to do this with the stored procedure. If you can do the INSERT directly, you can batch them with INSERT INTO ... VALUES (row1), (row2), ...

And Python can automate this if you use cursor.executemultiple()

I don't see the point of the function. It commits changes without opening a transaction and doesn't roll back on an exception, obviously leaving it for the caller. So in the caller there's exception handling code but no commit.
That said, i don't see anything in the code provided that would cause poor performance.
Check one of the following:

self.connection is some sort of poorly written getter that doesn't actually store the connection object but simply opens a new one, which is relatively expensive.
the stored procedure simply takes this long.
you might be passing/getting 10mb (huge json or binary) of arguments to the procedure through a 1mbps connection. I glanced through the callproc method of mysql's python library and it seems to fetch something inside callproc, so even if you're not fetching anything, it might.

I don't see this as a use case for multithreading. Multiprocessing might help, but if the procedure is taking milliseconds from other applications and yours is taking 1-2 seconds, multiprocessing is a hack that should be your last resort. You'd have to open individual connections per process and depending on the logic inside the stored procedure, it might gain you nothing at all.
